# Validate JTextField while typing in

Tags: java, swing, validation

I have a textfield, and i want to validate the textfield's input while i'm typing in. Just like the google register form. I tried to use thread. But it looks like a mess.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134329/jtextfields-real-time-formatting-of-user-input) and you might find something useful.

Comment: @VasilisG., no. Don't use a KeyListener. Use the DocumentListener or a JFormattedTextField.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a textfield, and i want to validate the textfield's input while i'm typing in. Just like the google register form. I tried to use thread. But it looks like a mess.

You don't have to use a thread to check the input as you type. You can use the [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) that is implemented for this purpose.

It can listen to the changes in the textfield as you type in the textfield, i.e. type characters / remove characters.

Comment: Thank you. I find Document Listener very useful. I understand the insertUpdate() and removeUpdate method. But I don't actually know when to use the changedUpdate method. Could you show me an example?

Comment: Yeah. I understood it though. The changedUpdate only occurs when you change the size, font,...of inputs. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: @John you can thank me by clicking the hollow looking tick beside my answer. That's also an indication that you problem has been solved with my help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyListener for this TextField.

This is example:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;  

public class JtextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JFrame f= new JFrame("TextField Example");  

            JTextField t1;  
            t1=new JTextField("Welcome, Give me a world");  
            t1.setBounds(50,100, 200,30);  

            f.add(t1);  
            f.setSize(400,400);  
            f.setLayout(null);  
            f.setVisible(true);  

             t1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("keyTyped");
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("keyReleased");
                }

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("keyPressed");
                }
            }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Swing has newer and better API's as was suggested by the answer to use a `DocumentListener`.